# Firebase java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I read many similar questions but couldn't figure out how to solve my problem.

I got this class where I receive cloud-messaging notifications from firebase:

```
public class FirebaseMessagingServiceImpl extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private final static String TAG = "FirebaseMessaging";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Message from " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            final String content = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            final String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            Log.i(TAG, "...with content: " + content);

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    UserInterfaceUtils.getAlertDialog(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            title,
                            content,
                            android.R.string.ok,
                            android.R.string.no,
                            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert,
                            null, null,
                            true, false).show();
                }
            });
        }
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
    }
}
```

From there I want to create an `alert.dialog`. But I get this `IllegalStateException`. When I log the string of the `getApplicationContext()` I get this: `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication@42585d08`

I am very stuck here and have no clue how to solve this.

For completeness here my getAlertDialog-method:

```
public static AlertDialog.Builder getAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, int pos, int neg, int icon, final Callable posFunc, final Callable negFunc, boolean posButton, boolean negButton) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.ShopDialogTheme);
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        }

        builder.setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(Html.fromHtml(message));

        if (posButton)
            builder.setPositiveButton(pos, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    try {
                        posFunc.call();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        if (negButton)
            builder.setNegativeButton(neg, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    try {
                        negFunc.call();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setIcon(icon);
        return builder;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title it sounds like whatever Activity you have when your code is running is extending Activity, and it needs to extend an AppCompatActivity, and whatever theme you have in you res/styles.xml that your activity uses should be an AppCompat theme.

Comment: It is a service which is defined in the manifest. So there is no theme applied to it.

Comment: yes, but are you calling the service from an activity?

Comment: No, I am not. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: You must have an activity that is running, my guess is that the application context is likely using the theme from that activity. So whatever activity is running is likely not an AppCompatActivity.

Comment: The Activity that is running at the time the error occurs is an AppCompatActivity.